# Styling The Background of An Active Superfish Menu Option

Tags: css, css-selectors, superfish

Im using a superfish menu with the class .sf-menu to do a menu. I wish on hover of the ul li for the li before to stay a certain background colour. My code for the menu is this :

```
<ul class="sf-menu" id="example">
        <li class="current">
            <a href="followed.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="followed.html">Knives</a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="followed.html">Cardsharp4 natural</a></li>
                        <li><a href="followed.html">Cardsharp4 black</a></li>
                        <li><a href="followed.html">Cardsharp3 natural</a></li>
                        <li><a href="followed.html">Cardsharp2 black</a></li>
                        <li><a href="followed.html">Cardsharp2 natural</a></li>

                </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="followed.html">Flashlights</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="followed.html">Flashlight 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="followed.html">Flashlight 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="followed.html">Flashlight 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="followed.html">Flashlight 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="followed.html">Camera</a>
        </li>   
        <li>
            <a href="followed.html">E-Bike</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Ive tried 4 different selectors and none seem to work :S

```
.sf-menu ul li > .sf-menu li {background-color: #ffffff;}
.sf-menu ul li > li a {background-color: #ffffff;}
.sf-menu ul ul li:hover.active ul li a {background-color: #ffffff;}
.sf-menu ul li ul li:hover.active ul li {background-color: #ffffff;}
```

Please can anyone advise myself.

thankyou

Comment: Can you please make this point lil clear? *to do a menu... I wish on hover of the ul li for the li before to stay a certain background colour.*

Comment: sorry i didnt realise it was so unclear :S

Comment: Do you want to hover the child li? the one which opens in the dropdown?

Comment: yes :) i do, basically when i hover over the li, i want its parent to stay a background colour

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96798895/drive%20-%20Copy.html I reckon u don't want this right, you want the color of the sub menu to turn orange too, on hover, right?

Comment: basically its a black background, on hover its grey, and when i roll over the sub menu i want it to stay grey?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gPkDY/2/)**

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/jQD7W/1/)**

make a class of .current

```
.current{
    background-color:red;
    color:red;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```